# Why does visual studio give me this error type expected

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm Developing windows phone 8.1 application when i want to start emulator Give me this error "Type expected" line 27 this is the line of code:

```
statusBar.BackgroundColor = new ((SolidColorBrush)Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"]);
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is clear, you are not telling the type name:

```
statusBar.BackgroundColor = new (...);
                         -------^
```

Now, you've got a [`SolidColorBrush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush) (after casting) but you're trying to get a [`Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color). Fortunately, `SolidColorBrush` has a [`Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.color) property which is what I suspect you want:

```
var brush = (SolidColorBrush) Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];
statusBar.BackgroundColor = brush.Color;
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush' to 'Windows.UI.Color?' GeoNote E:\Projects\GeoNote\GeoNote\MapNotes\MainPage.xaml.cs 27

Comment: @MrEko: See my edit. But really, you should know what you're *trying* to achieve - we explained the error message, and you should be able to take it from there. If you're really just trying random things to get it to compile, you should take a step back and think about the bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the `new` operator, which requires a type, like this:

```
variable = new SomeType(constructorArguments);
```

You've got `new` and then a cast.

I *suspect* you just want the cast, without `new`:

```
// With a using directive for Windows.UI.Xaml...
statusBar.BackgroundColor = (SolidColorBrush) Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush' to 'Windows.UI.Color?' GeoNote E:\Projects\GeoNote\GeoNote\MapNotes\MainPage.xaml.cs 27